# Entity setup for tableview data

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying out `Core Data` for the first time and I'm not sure I fully understand how to set up my data model.  I will be displaying my data in a `Table View` with custom `table view cells`.  Each table view cell will have the following (all unique): an `NSURL` (for an audio file), a `UIImage`, an `AVAsset`, and an `NSString`.  Would I only need to make one `Entity` (This is for a single user based application)?  Also,since there aren't attribute types for `AVAsset`, `UIImage`, etc.. would I need to convert these to data types?

Comment: There are a number of considerations that will assist any person providing a useful answer that will help you. Could you please provide some additional detail that identifies whether you know how to set up a new data model (in project inspector is a file with extension `.xcdatamodeld`), whether you have already prepared a Core Data stack, whether you have implemented an instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` in your table view? Etc.